# Python.exe in incorrect path despite adding path to Windows

Tags: python, site-packages

I added the following python paths to the Path in Windows for system variables.

```
C:\Project1\python\Python310-32\Scripts
C:\Project1\python\Python310-32
```

When I run pip upgrade I get the following error:

```
Unable to create process using '"C:\Project0\python\Python310-32\python.exe"  "C:\Project1\python\Python310-32\Scripts\pip.exe" upgrade': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My question is despite me adding the path to the system variables, restarting the computer multiple times, why is my python.exe still pointed to an old project in project0 instead of project 1.

I am trying to install/get a particular package under site-packages to install/work for my project. But that particular library under site-packages isn't being found.

Comment: Is that Python310-32-directory created with `virtualenv`?

Comment: I am unsure, I downloaded the project from Github. Followed directions to add the path in system variables. How do I find out?

Comment: Does Python310-32 -directory contain file `pyvenv.cfg`, or do the Scripts-directory contain files starting `activate`?

Comment: No they don't...

Comment: OK, what is the output of the following command? (give the path explicitly, do not use PATH):
`C:\Project1\python\Python310-32\Scripts\pip --version`

Comment: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Project0\python\Python310-32\python.exe"  "C:\Project1\python\Python310-32\Scripts\pip.exe" --version': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253117/discussion-between-juha-and-yash-jain).

Comment: I found the solution. Check below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

Update the 'PATH' environment variable to include:

```
C:\<path>\python\Python310-32\Scripts\;
C:\<path>\python\Python310-32\
```

Update or create 'PYTHONHOME' environment variable to include:

```
C:\<path>\python\Python310-32\
```

Update or create 'PYTHONPATH' environment variable to include:

```
C:\<path>\python\Python310-32\Scripts\;
C:\<path>\python\Python310-32\
```