# How to fix Windows system incorrectly assuming python.exe path?

Tags: python, windows, pip, path-variables

I'm trying to run a pip installation on my Windows machine using the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But when I try to execute that command, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\python.exe"  "C:\Users\[my user]\.local\bin\pip.exe" install -r requirements.txt': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The evident thing here is that it's looking for the `python.exe` file in an incorrect folder.

This folder used to be in the PATH environment variable for my user, and I've since removed it. I've also reinstalled Python without that folder in the PATH variable, but even then I still get that error. Is there a manual way to tell the system specifically that `python.exe` is in the `\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\` path and not the one it assumes it is in?
I also followed the instructions in the best answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75998242/python-exe-in-incorrect-path-despite-adding-path-to-windows) made prior in the site.

EDIT: using `where python` yields the following:

```
C:\Users\[my user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

EDIT 2: using `echo %PATH%` does show the folders that contain `python.exe` and `pip.exe`.

By the way, there is in fact a `pip.exe` in the path the error provides.

Comment: What does happen if you try `which python` or `where python`?

Comment: generally speaking if you issue a command at a command line with a file name that has no path, you want to be in the same folder as the file (commands will usually check the current folder when searching for an unqualified file name). Otherwise - use the full path to the file (requirements.txt). Same is true for your python executable. So if python, Pip, and requirements.txt are all in different folders and not in your PATH -- guess you will need to fully qualify some of these names.

Comment: `pip.exe` contains the path to `python.exe`. Try to find the `pip.exe` which was installed with your Python version (should be in a directory `Scripts` below the `python.exe`). You  can copy this `pip.exe` to the place where the other `pip.exe` resides and replace it (better make a copy, just in case).

Comment: *"This folder used to be in the PATH environment variable for my user"* -- and what about the system environment variables? Do you see the folder path when you `echo %PATH%` in CMD? Did you open a new CMD/Powershell after removing the folder from your PATH environment variable? Side note, `pip` uses `python2` on my Windows 11 machine, `pip3` uses `python3`.

Comment: The effective PATH variable for your user is the system path variable, combined with the specific path variable for your user. If you only changed the path variable for your user, and the old path is still part of the path variable for the system, that's your problem. If neither saved path variable has the old path, try restarting your system as a quick way to ensure you're not just looking at a value cached someplace.

Answer (score -1):

The `pip.exe` file consists of a simple launcher stub executable, followed by a shebang line containing the path to the actual launcher (to the wrong `python.exe` in this case) and finally a ZIP-file containing a python script which should be executed by the python executable.

Details about the launcher stub can be found at https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/simple_launcher/src/master/

If the shebang line contains the absolute path (usually this is the case and seems the case here), playing around with the `PATH` environment variable won't do anything as long as the same `pip.exe` is launched.

Solution is to find the `pip.exe` which was installed with your Python version (should be in a directory `Scripts` below the `python.exe`). You can copy this `pip.exe` and replace the `C:\Users\[my user]\.local\bin\pip.exe` with it.

The slightly more complicated option would be to modify the `pip.exe` with a hex editor to set the right path.

Comment: I think what Michael wants to point out by this answer is that the virtual environment pip.exe belongs to was created using a Python version that does not exist anymore and thus the reference points to nowhere. This causes the problem. Now you can try to modify the old venv so that it points to an existing Python installation or simply create a new venv using the installed Python version. Search for pip.exe to find the venv path.